# How can I access items in a dynamically allocated array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, struct

I'm in a class right now that works with C and one of my assignments requires that I work with a struct that my professor wrote for us. It's actually two structs, with one struct basically containing an array of the first struct.

Here's what they look like:

```
typedef struct cityStruct
{
    unsigned int zip;
    char *town
} city;
typedef struct zipTownsStruct
{
    int *towns;
    city **zips;
    city *cities
} zipTowns;
```

And here's my function for allocating memory for the `zipTowns` structure:

```
void getArrs(zipTowns *arrs, int size)
{
    arrs->towns = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    arrs->zips = malloc(sizeof(city **) * size);
    arrs->cities = malloc(sizeof(city *) * size);
}
```

From what I understand, what I'm doing here is allocating space in memory for a certain number of `int`s, `city` pointers, and `city` structures, based on the size variable. I understand that this is basically what an array is.

I'm having trouble with understanding how I can access these arrays and manipulate items in it. Writing this gives me an error:

```
strcpy(arrs.cities[0]->town, "testTown\0");
```

You can see what I'm trying to do here. I want to access each "City" in the `zipTowns` struct by index and insert a value.

How can I access the items in these dynamically allocated array of structures?

Comment: What does the error say? IOW, is `cities` an array os structs or an array of pointers?

Comment: Notice your `int * towns` allocates `sizeof(int) * size`, not `sizeof(int*) * size`. Your allocation pointer arithmetic is off by one reference for the other two fields; your `city * * zips` should allocate `sizeof(city * ) * size` and your `city * cities` should allocate `sizeof(city) * size`.

Comment: I guess the purpose of the class exercise is to teach you how to use pointers. Search online for a good tutorial on them if you cannot follow your trainer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of `x->y` as `(*x).y`.

`arrs` is not a structure, it's a pointer to a structure, and `cities` is not a pointer to a pointer to a structure, it's just a pointer to a structure.

Use `arrs->cities[0].town` instead of `arrs.cities[0]->town`.

However, you're still not allocating enough room for these structures. This should make it clearer what you're doing with the allocations, and should also give you enough room for your data:

```
arrs->towns = malloc(sizeof(*arrs->towns) * size);
arrs->zips = malloc(sizeof(*arrs->zips) * size);
arrs->cities = malloc(sizeof(*arrs->cities) * size);
```

With the second and third, you were only allocating enough room for a pointer to be stored instead of the actual data type.

With this approach, you will be able to access from `arrs->cities[0]` to `arrs->cities[9]` and you also will be able to access the members of each `city` by doing `arrs->cities[<number>].<member>`.

You also do not need to intentionally null-terminate your strings. This is already done for you. Therefore, you can replace `"testTown\0"` with `"testTown"`.